# Azure ACR - how to assign service principle through terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to assign a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal) to an Azure container registry to no avail. The [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication) state the following...

> You can assign a service principal to your registry, and your application or service can use it for headless authentication

I wish to do this through terraform, but I do not see any sort of service principal option in the [Azure provider `azurerm_container_registry` docs (managed)](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/container_registry.html#managed-container-registry)...

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "resourceGroup1"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                   = "containerRegistry1"
  resource_group_name    = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location               = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  sku                    = "Premium"
  admin_enabled          = false
  georeplication_locations = ["East US", "West Europe"]
}
```

I was hoping to find a `service_principal` stanza such as what is available in the [`azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html)...

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "test" {

  // [...]

  service_principal {
    client_id     = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    client_secret = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
  }
}
```

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? There seems to be a disconnect with a lot of the Azure resources on how service principals play a part. I assume evolving APIs are to blame, but this seems like a simple ask... Perhaps I'm totally off base here. Thoughts?

Comment: Any more question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something different between the AKS and ACR with the Service Principal.

For AKS, it needs to create a secret for the pods or services to access the ACR and the secret is set in the yaml file. So it needs both client_id and client_secret at the same time.

But for ACR, you need a Service Principal with specific permission associated with it for others to access it. So you just need to assign the Service Principal to the ACR with the permission setting and client_id. The terraform code would like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "resourceGroup1"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                   = "containerRegistry1"
  resource_group_name    = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location               = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  sku                    = "Premium"
  admin_enabled          = false
  georeplication_locations = ["East US", "West Europe"]
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal" "test" {
  application_id = "${azurerm_azuread_application.test.application_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password" "test" {
  service_principal_id = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal.test.id}"
  value                = "VT=uSgbTanZhyz@%nL9Hpd+Tfay_MRV#"
  end_date             = "2020-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "test" {
  scope              = "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.id}"
  role_definition_id = "Contributor"
  principal_id       = "${azurerm_azuread_service_principal_password.test.service_principal_id}"
}
```

For more details, see [azurerm_role_assignment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html). Hope this will help you. If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: Cool, makes sense. And yea I've actually done this. I was getting unauthorized errors unrelated with a bad cli package that was a red herring. Upgrading dissolved the noauth errors. But yea, service principal can indeed auth to the registry - thanks!